# Facebook isn't working on any of my browsers (But other sites are)

Tags: networking, dns, facebook

Other websites are working fine. I decided to reinstall my Ubuntu today for a fresh start. Facebook was working fine at first. I turn my laptop back on later in the day and I can no longer access Facebook. It comes up with the following;

```
This site can’t be reached

facebook.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I'm a complete Linux noob so can someone help me out? I looked around on the internet and I couldn't find solid answer.

Any and all responses will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `nslookup facebook.com`?

Comment: I don't even know what that means! Please can you explain to me as simply as possible what you want me to do?

Comment: Now it's working for some reason!

Comment: Press CTRL+ALT+T. That will open a terminal window. Then type that command, and please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/904492/edit) your answer to include the output.

Comment: Please also add the output of `nslookup facebook.com 8.8.8.8` for comparison.

Comment: If it wasn't working and now it is - without you having changed a thing - I think the problem was likely with your DNS provider.